# Custom CSS code causing erratic scrollbar behavior in chrome

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

The following code results in the scrollbar not being clickable and/or draggable, and this happens arbitrarily in Chrome only.

Is there anything obvious in the code that's causing this?
 - If so, how should be fixed?
 - If not, how do I continue to troubleshoot it?

I tried working the Chrome debugger but clicking on the sidebar does not reveal anything useful.

```css
html {
max-width: 780px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
background-image:url('https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-styled-pattern-background_1048-6593.jpg');
background-size: 116px;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

header {
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
margin-bottom:23px;
}

#logo {
margin-left:15px;
}

#forum-link {
max-width:110px;
margin-right:35px;
}

#forum-link a{
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:x-large;
}

footer
{
text-align:center;
font-size:small;
}

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
html{
 margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body{
 margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
  }

header{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

#logo {
 margin:initial;
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content:center;
}

#forum-link {
  margin: initial;
 max-width:initial;
 background:#323232;
  height: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 100%;
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content:center;
}

#forum-link a{
font-weight:bold;
font-size:.9em;
}
#forum-link a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

#content{
  flex: 1;
 margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
<div id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/354/85" srcset="http://placekitten.com/g/354/85 1x, http://placekitten.com/g/354/85 2x" width="354" height="85"></a></div>
<div id="forum-link"><a href="/forum">Join our Forums!</a></div>
</header>

<div id="content">
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<h2>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</h2>
<h3>"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</h3>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae aliquam mi. Nam in dictum nulla. Donec sit amet mollis nunc. Aliquam a elit quis felis finibus accumsan. Vivamus vel pellentesque mauris. Integer et commodo lectus. Donec fermentum urna ac lorem euismod fermentum. Aliquam porttitor, lacus id consectetur auctor, velit est mollis risus, iaculis aliquet massa massa in velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur et semper orci, sed rhoncus purus. Cras rhoncus accumsan libero nec sagittis. Proin ac ipsum suscipit tortor tincidunt malesuada et at sapien. Morbi mollis ultricies lacus ut blandit.
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pellentesque sagittis mi. Proin commodo tempor sem at euismod. Nam vel porta mauris. Nunc rutrum libero vitae dui tincidunt, eget condimentum mi semper. Cras gravida nunc vel pulvinar tempor. Nunc rhoncus rutrum justo, vel facilisis ex fringilla in. Sed posuere ex non eros ultrices varius.
<p>
Fusce vestibulum quis arcu ac dapibus. Maecenas felis ante, auctor sed congue ut, convallis a arcu. Nunc vel maximus quam. Nam mauris purus, commodo et leo vel, volutpat sollicitudin libero. Mauris porta lectus nibh, et suscipit ipsum condimentum elementum. Sed sem lectus, aliquet id condimentum id, maximus eget felis. Sed ornare augue libero, eget hendrerit sem porttitor vitae. Ut porttitor vehicula dapibus. Suspendisse at accumsan orci.
<p>
In ante eros, condimentum id elit quis, sagittis bibendum arcu. Phasellus in metus quam. Sed gravida condimentum mi sit amet molestie. Ut blandit tempus libero ut porta. Sed blandit sem eget mi rutrum, at lacinia risus efficitur. Duis rhoncus porta lacus, scelerisque scelerisque tellus sodales quis. Nunc maximus ex et placerat commodo. Curabitur quis bibendum tortor. Sed condimentum vel urna laoreet mollis. Quisque molestie orci sed sodales porttitor.
<p>
Morbi ipsum erat, varius eu eros id, porta vestibulum nulla. In mattis dolor nisi, ut luctus dolor cursus a. Phasellus tempor diam enim, a accumsan justo dignissim sit amet. Vestibulum congue, arcu non accumsan rutrum, tortor augue sodales lacus, eu fermentum leo odio eu nibh. Cras non urna non leo imperdiet varius. Vestibulum eget magna metus. Curabitur eu tempor magna.
</div>

<footer>
<div id="copyright">&copy; Copyright text</div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: i cannot see anything wrong in the code. I was able to scroll